# Allow colon (:) in URL on Azure Web App

Tags: azure, url, azure-web-app-service

We are trying to expose a URL following the [ARK](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kunze-ark-18) standard (Archival Resource Key) from an ASP.NET website hosted on an Azure Web App. But it seems Azure Web Apps do not support colons (:) in URL path segments, as we are getting an HTTP 500 error code with message "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." when trying to type a URL like http://example.azurewebsites.net/ark:/123/456.

Note that we did update our web.config's [`RequestPathInvalidCharacters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestpathinvalidcharacters.aspx) setting to allow colons in URIs, and it works locally. Also, colons in URIs may not be very frequent but are [valid](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3), even [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Welcome) uses them.

---

Edit:

Well after a few tests, it looks like the issue happens only when the colon is at the end of a path segment (e.g. : http://example.azurewebsites.net/ark:/123/456). Otherwise, the `requestPathInvalidCharacters` setting applies. No luck for us: the ARK standard specifies that the colon be placed at the end of a path segment.

Note that the error displayed in this case is different from the error when `requestPathInvalidCharacters` has its default value and a colon is placed in the middle of a path segment. Here the error seems to happen even before the request enters the IIS pipeline (maybe at the Azure level). You can test the above URL for a quick display of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my origin reply. I try it with Azure MVC API. I configure the map route as following:

```html
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}:{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

And add the requestPathInvalidCharacters in web.config:

```html
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>
```

ValuesController:

```html
  // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return id.ToString();
        }
```

After deploy to Azure I could get the result from the URL:http://.azurewebsites.net/api/values:5

[image]

Comment: We need to implement Archival Resource Key for our client whose crawler is based on this standard, so not putting colons in URLs is really not an option. The only alternative I can think of right now is to host the website outside of Azure (at least the part handling this protocol). A lot of additional development and maintainance for a trivial use case...

Comment: Sorry for my incorrect reply, I test again and could use colon url to get the result from the MVC API. Please see my edited reply. Hope it could meet your requirement.

Comment: Well after a few tests, it looks like the issue happens only when the colon is at the end of a path segment (e.g. : http://example.azurewebsites.net/ark:/123/456). Otherwise, the `requestPathInvalidCharacters` setting applies. No luck for us: the ARK standard specifies that the colon be placed at the end of a path segment.

Comment: Note that the error displayed in this case is different from the error when `requestPathInvalidCharacters` has its default value and a colon is placed in the middle of a path segment. Here the error seems to happen even *before* the request enters the IIS pipeline (maybe at the Azure level). You can test the above URL for a quick display of the problem.